# MSMQ - message body is unreadable

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

I have downloaded and deployed an example of [MSMQ client and service](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-10-31-14-05/MSMQ-Example.zip),  from an [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/schlepticons/archive/2012/05/29/simple-wcf-netmsmq-example-or-step-1-to-stop-reinventing-yet-another-msmq-clone.aspx).

It works quite well (after I fixed some namespaces). But when I open the Message Queuing tool (built in Windows) and try to examine the message body, it looks quite strange:

> 00 01 00 01 04 02 24 6E ......$n
>
> 65 74 2E 6D 73 6D 71 3A et.msmq:
>
> 2F 2F 6C 6F 63 61 6C 68 //localh
>
> 6F 73 74 2F 70 72 69 76 ost/priv
>
> 61 74 65 2F 6D 79 51 75 ate/myQu
>
> 65 75 65 03 07 56 02 0B eue..V..
>
> 01 73 04 0B 01 61 06 56 .s...a.V
>
> 08 44 0A 1E 00 82 99 39 .D...9
>
> 75 72 6E 3A 5A 69 6D 6D urn:Zimm
>
> 73 2F 53 61 6D 70 6C 65 s/Sample
>
> 73 2F 6E 65 74 4D 73 6D s/netMsm
>
> 71 2F 49 53 65 72 76 69 q/IServi
>
> 63 65 50 72 6F 63 65 73 ceProces
>
> 73 6F 72 2F 53 75 62 6D sor/Subm
>
> 69 74 4D 65 73 73 61 67 itMessag
>
> 65 40 17 56 73 44 65 62 e@.VsDeb
>
> 75 67 67 65 72 43 61 75 uggerCau
>
> 73 61 6C 69 74 79 44 61 salityDa
>
> 74 61 08 41 68 74 74 70 ta.Ahttp
>
> 3A 2F 2F 73 63 68 65 6D ://schem
>
> 61 73 2E 6D 69 63 72 6F as.micro
>
> 73 6F 66 74 2E 63 6F 6D soft.com
>
> 2F 76 73 74 75 64 69 6F /vstudio
>
> 2F 64 69 61 67 6E 6F 73 /diagnos
>
> 74 69 63 73 2F 73 65 72 tics/ser
>
> 76 69 63 65 6D 6F 64 65 vicemode
>
> 6C 73 69 6E 6B 9F 3C B8 lsink<¸
>
> 80 CF A3 B1 65 61 39 AF Ï£±ea9¯
>
> 8E 52 4C B3 BF 2F 72 1F RL³¿/r.
>
> E3 7D 05 00 00 00 00 07 ã}......
>
> 01 F3 09 0E 56 2E 41 9E .ó..V.A
>
> 63 BA 18 56 DE 5D D7 10 cº.VÞ]×.
>
> 53 92 73 3C 3C 77 45 B5 Ss<
>
> B6 85 24 2B 02 E1 0E 00 ¶$+.á..
>
> 09 00 00 44 0C 1E 00 82 ...D...
>
> 99 24 6E 65 74 2E 6D 73 $net.ms
>
> 6D 71 3A 2F 2F 6C 6F 63 mq://loc
>
> 61 6C 68 6F 73 74 2F 70 alhost/p
>
> 72 69 76 61 74 65 2F 6D rivate/m
>
> 79 51 75 65 75 65 01 56 yQueue.V
>
> 0E 40 0D 53 75 62 6D 69 .@.Submi
>
> 74 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 tMessage
>
> 08 19 75 72 6E 3A 5A 69 ..urn:Zi
>
> 6D 6D 73 2F 53 61 6D 70 mms/Samp
>
> 6C 65 73 2F 6E 65 74 4D les/netM
>
> 73 6D 71 40 07 72 65 71 smq@.req
>
> 75 65 73 74 99 24 38 36 uest$86
>
> 61 63 36 61 39 32 2D 64 ac6a92-d
>
> 37 36 34 2D 34 35 62 37 764-45b7
>
> 2D 39 36 38 34 2D 37 65 -9684-7e
>
> 64 39 65 36 30 30 35 65 d9e6005e
>
> 33 66 01 01 01          3f...

Is it because the message is encrypted?
How to disable the encryption so I can clearly see the message?

I am using Windows 7 and MSMQ 4.0

UPDATE

This blog article has an example of unencrypted readable message in MSMQ:
  http://ardalis.com/how-can-i-view-msmq-messages-and-queues

This is what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? It looks exactly like I'd expect a message from that application to look.

Comment: @DanielMann - I would expect to see plain text. I have another MSMQ example and I can see its messages as plain text: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Id>ef3e5487-9f79-425c-ad6c-3e1d6aac1cc4</Id>
 <Details>Some order details;</Details>
</Order>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue Explorer has solved the problem:

http://www.cogin.com/msmq/QueueExplorer/QueueExplorer2.2.php

Solution was suggested at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962080/1131855